# Is there a way to disable Material UI expansion panel's animation?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, mui

I want to disable the animation of Material UI expansion panel in React.
How can I disable all the animations applied to the expansion panel?

Tried overwriting the transitions but it didn't help. Let me know how you would overwrite that.

PS: If that is not possible let me know any other light weight expansion panel (accordion) to use with styling customization.

Comment: Almost everything in MD CSS is marked as '!important'. I would try to overwrite the css that does this marking your overwrite as '!important' as well, so that it cascades over it properly.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard Material-UI (the React component library referenced in the question -- not Material Design) has almost no uses of "!important" in its styling.

Comment: @ShahLav [`ExpansionPanel` unconditionally uses](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanel/ExpansionPanel.js#L168) the [`Collapse`](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/) transition. What kind of styling customization are you trying to make?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You can do this by manipulating the TransitionProps prop, as such:

```
  <ExpansionPanel
    defaultExpanded
    square
    TransitionProps={{
      timeout: 0
    }}
  >
```

The **timeout: 0** prop can be discovered by looking at the *Collapse* API, which is the default *TransitionComponent* of *ExpansionPanel*: https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/

Comment: This seems to have no effect when I put it in my tag. The transition animation is still there.

Comment: Actually, looking at this further, I see that this setting does affect the actual collapse/expand transition itself, however there seems to be no way to get at the transition on the expandIcon (which happens to be what I wanted to disable, so it's the main thing I was looking at). Very frustrating that this isn't exposed somehow too.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

`<Accordion disableGutters={true}>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following css to disable the Animation on Material-UI Accordion:

```
.MuiCollapse-container {
  transition-duration:0s!important
}
```

You can probably also apply it on the Expansion Panel collapsing div

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but you can override the css for the expand icon and change the transform property to `rotate(0deg)` to disable the animation on the icon.

```
.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expandIcon.Mui-expanded {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

More details on customization can be found [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b208789c8b5d659c984c44a323ac8fc27a2c8d98/docs/src/pages/customization/how-to-customize/how-to-customize.md)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having trouble with the MUI Expansion Panel or Accordion component expansion animation, this will cause it to simply open and close in a reasonable amount of time.

```
<Accordion
      disableGutters={true}
      TransitionProps={{ timeout: { appear: 1, enter: 1, exit: 4 } }}
    >
```